# Strange display when developing a Visual Studio 2013 Extension "*.vsix"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I am working on a VS2013 extension. When pressing `Ctrl + F5` to run the extension from the Visual Studio development environment, I see the following strange display:

[image]

It seems the `syntax highlighting` is still working, but only each line is colored *excessively* in purple.

**But if I install my VS extension and run it by starting VS normally. The display is OK.**

Anyone knows how to fix it?  Is this some VS bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.

I added a `Editor Classifier` which contains the following default implementation:

```
public UDKBuildDescriptionFileEditorFormat()
{
    this.DisplayName = "UDKBuildDescriptionFileEditor"; //human readable version of the name
    this.BackgroundColor = Colors.BlueViolet; // <-- HERE
    this.TextDecorations = System.Windows.TextDecorations.Underline; // <-- HERE
}
```

I once added this editor classifier to my VSIX package and run it with `Ctrl + F5`. But it seems after I removed it from VSIX. Visual Studio doesn't know to auto remove it when running with `Ctrl + F5`.

The solution is, to manually uninstall this editor classifier from `Tools -> Extensions and Updates`.